# How to draw a route by using different lat long values?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing an application related to map activity.

Based on my requirements I am saving many lat long values in my db,
as follows:

id      lat            long
 1      17.490431     78.407435
 2       17.488221    78.409667
 3      17.48249      78.414559 
 4      17.470292      78.426747

My requirement is to get all lat/long from the db and draw the route by using the lat/long.

If any one knows the solution please help me.

Comment: You mean, by using those points you want to draw a root path by adding them...

Comment: ya by using those points,i want to draw root path

Comment: Then, you dont know how to draw a path between two geo points?? If you know that one, why cant you move to draw a path from point1 to point2 and point2 to point3... Any problem in this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st you have to know how to draw route between two Geo points.

[Distance calculation from my location to destination location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683554/distance-calculation-from-my-location-to-destination-location-in-android)

[Android - To draw a route between two geo points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222396/android-to-draw-a-route-between-two-geo-points)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551034/how-to-draw-line-between-two-pointslatitude-and-longitude-in-google-map-in-and

[Draw route by getting my point to destination point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393589/draw-route-by-getting-my-point-to-destination-point)

[drawing routes with the help of latitude and longitude values saved in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275140/drawing-routes-with-the-help-of-latitude-and-longitude-values-saved-in-database)

Follow the link and surf net.there have many resource there.

Comment: provide a proper example. links may become broken overtime leaving this answer useless.